# why 'setprofile' print this

Tags: python, sys

```
import sys
def a():
    print 'aaa'
def profiler(frame, event, arg):
    print event, frame.f_code.co_name, frame.f_lineno, "->", arg

# profiler is activated on the next call, return, or exception
sys.setprofile(profiler)
a()
```

print

```
call a 5 -> None#what is it
aaa
return a 6 -> None#what is it 
return <module> 12 -> None#what is it
```

why print this.

Comment: The real question is, what do you expect it to print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `profiler` function gets called at each profiling event because you called `sys.setprofile` on it.

Each time it's called, it prints a line, because you put an unconditional `print` statement as its body.  **Why** you did that, is hard for us to tell you, making your "why" questions really, truly peculiar.

Profiling events are just calls and returns, per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html?highlight=setprofile#sys.setprofile):

> ```
> 'call'
> ```
>
> A function is called (or some other
>   code block entered).
>
> ```
> 'return'
> ```
>
> A function (or other code block) is
>   about to return.
>
> ```
> 'c_call'
> ```
>
> A C function is about to be called.
>   This may be an extension function or a
>   built-in.
>
> ```
> 'c_return'
> ```
>
> A C function has returned.

Here's what *I* observe (Python 2.5 or 2.6, MacOSX) in a slightly simpler, sharper case:

```
>>> def a():
...     print 'aaa'
... 
>>> def profiler(frame, event, arg):
...     print 'PROF %r %r' % (event, arg)
... 
>>> sys.setprofile(profiler)
PROF 'return' None
>>> a()
PROF 'call' None
PROF 'c_call' <built-in function utf_8_decode>
PROF 'c_return' <built-in function utf_8_decode>
PROF 'return' (u'a()\n', 4)
PROF 'call' None
PROF 'call' None
aaa
PROF 'return' None
PROF 'return' None
```

Not sure why you don't see the `c_call` and `c_return` cases as you should -- maybe there is no implicit `utf-8` conversion for printing in your specific platform (what OS? what level of Python? what IDE if any).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like maybe you're wondering why arg is None.  `arg` has different meanings for each event.  For "return", `arg` is the value to be returned.  For "exception", it's a triple of exception information.  See http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.settrace for more information.